# cakephp/php run function in background

Tags: php, cakephp, exec, background-process, pcntl

I've never done this before, so I need some input.

Code (in general):

```
$cofig = Configure::read('config');
    if ($config['stuff'] == 1){
      $this->Session->setFlash('it is already done this month');
      $this->redirect('/to/some/where');
    }
    elseif ($config['stuff'] == 2){
      $this->Session->setFlash('it is already running');
      $this->redirect('/to/some/where');
    }
    else {
      SomeComponent::SomeFunction(); //this I need to launch in background while user continues further
      $this->Session->setFlash('you have launched it');
      $this->redirect('/to/some/where');
    }
```

"SomeComponent" contains several functions. I need to launch a specific function "SomeFunction()" in the bacground while user continues further.
Function "SomeComponent::SomeFunction()" generates bunch of pdfs, interacts with database and uses Cakephp specific methods'n'crap to do all that. Users receive output via database, so I don't need to retrieve it form the function itself.
So i'm not clear which method can do that, which best to use and what are/may be drawbacks of each one (security issues in particular).

I hope I explained everything in a understandable way. If you have read this far - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is that process "SomeComponent::SomeFunction()" taking too long? If the answer is yes then I would wrap that function in [a shell](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#console-and-shells) and if you want to take it to the next level I would use an [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) in order to dispatch that background process.

[Here is](http://martinbean.co.uk/blog/2013/11/22/getting-to-grips-with-cakephps-events-system/) an introduction to Event Handling in CakePHP.

Comment: I came back to this project and created Observer pattern with CakeEvent. Everything works fine up to one point - user still has to wait until it completes (not dispatching as seperate process). I wouldnt say it takes too long, but it's long enough for user to interrupt it by refreshing, backing up or whatever magic the end-user is wielding.